# Ubuntu 16.04 and Intel XL710 SR-IOV - Packet drops

Tags: networking, server, kvm-virtualization

we have server running Ubuntu 16.4 KVM with Intel XL710 40Gbps NIC with SR-IOV on top of it.

On top of each 40G interfaces are created 4 SR-IOV VFs which are associated to VMs.

Problem is that after traffic load increases (approx 6Gbps on physical intf) we are expiriencing increased RTT and traffic drops.

VMs looks OK, switches and rest of the network also looks good and we are suspecting to SR-IOV.

How can I verify potential traffic drops on SR-IOV?

Has anybody similar expirience?

BR, Mate

Comment: I have same question